# Unable to restart apache. Website is also down

Tags: server, apache2, error-handling

So I spent quite a while looking around for solutions but I haven't been able to get anything. So yesterday I updated a few things and theeeen everything broke :v.

When I try to restart apache I get `* Restarting web server apache2

```
    [fail]
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/bw.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_bw.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_bw.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

I've checked the error log and there was nothing there ._.

This is what's on line 140 in apache2.conf

```
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
```

This is what's on line 1 in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/bw.load

```
LoadModule bw_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_bw.so
```

I'm kinda at a stand still here :v. Any help will be appreciated.

(I should also mention that I have Sentora installed. Annd my server is running Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: Have you checked if the file `mod_bw.so` exists e.g. by `ls -l /usr/lib/apache2/modules/` ?

Comment: I just checked. It does not exist

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an Ubuntu issue per se, so you're better off in an Apache area.

For a temp fix, just to get Apache running, comment out the LoadModule line.

And it's a sandbox project?

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/sandbox/mod_bw/mod_bw.txt
http://bwmod.sourceforge.net/

But that should give you the ability to (re-)install it.  Or re-compile it as the case may be.

Comment: So I commented out the LoadModule line buut I'm getting another error now

" The apache2 configtest failed. Not doing anything.
Output of config test was:
AH00534: apache2: Configuration error: More than one MPM loaded.
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information."

Comment: @DangerNoodle, I asked this to be moved to the Apache area.  Usually you can just follow the error trail and resolve them one at a time till it works though...  Best

Comment: @Michael there is no "Apache area" per se.  The question is on topic here, and does not need migrated anywhere.  (Migration request declined)